# Philosophische WÜHLER?

Tags: meaning

Which of the three - or rather the two last - Duden "Bedeutungen" of "Wühler"

https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Wuehler#bedeutungen

would according to normal German usage fit best into the below text (from ca. 1860)?:

> "Eine Zeit lang wird dieß als System- oder Styl-losigkeit erscheinen, und Mancher wird meinen am besten den Ton zu treffen, wenn er ganz unsystematisch, unzusammenhängend — „in Aphorismen und Blitzen“ — denkt.  **Philosophische Wühler** werden im Namen der (abstracten) Freiheit gegen „Systemzwang“ und „Schulfuchserei“, gegen alle Zucht und Ordnung ein fürchterliches Zetergeschrei erheben, gegen den speculativen Olymp in Titanen- (oder wenn man lieber will: Freischärler-) Weise heranstürmen und alle Elemente zu mischen suchen."

Answer (score 1):

Konrad benutzt in seinem Essay die Begriffe *Wühler* und *Wühlerei*. Im neunzehnten Jahrhundert haben diese beiden Wörter, wie das Grimmsche Wörterbuch belegt, eine spezifische Bedeutung, die sie heute nicht mehr haben und die in Vergessenheit geraten ist.

Das Verb *[wühlen](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GW27644#XGW27644)* bedeutet "umwälzen", und so sind die ***[Wühler](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GW27645#XGW27645)*** diejenigen Menschen, die die Umwälzungen vorantreiben, die in den deutschsprachigen Ländern im neunzehnten Jahrhundert stattfinden: die "verfechter demokratisch-republikanischer ideen". Bezeichnet werden sie so vor allem von denen, wie Konrad, die konservativ-reaktionäre Ansichten vertreten. Ein Wühler ist ein Revolutionär, ein Umstürzler, ein Anarchist, und in Konrads Text ist ein philosophischer Wühler jemand, der die philosophische Tradition umstürzen und, wie Konrad meint, unsystematisch denken will.

Comment: Willkommen, @SillyBob. Im Meta hatte sich die Community mal darauf geeinigt, dass Antworten in der Sprache verfasst werden, in der die Frage gestellt worden ist.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Da der Frager einen schwierigen Text zu lesen in der Lage ist (den er in seiner Frage zitiert), müsste er auch meine Antwort verstehen können. Im Übrigen enthalten die englischen Passagen seiner Fragen derart viele schwere Fehler, dass ich nicht sicher bin, ob er Englisch wirklich besser beherrscht als Deutsch.

Answer (score 0):

You would use "wühlen" to refer to reading through philosophical works seeking for an answer. So I'd say **3rd** meaning. Sadly, I dont have sufficient context to tell it for sure. Your text is linking something with the demonstrative pronoun "dies", but we do not know what that is!

On a more general level, your text is pretty dated, for one thing. It  dates back somwehere to the middle of the 19th century, and modern dictionaries may be misleading here.

Secondly, philosophical works often employ the language specific for one particular book in its context, and the role of the context is **extremely** big. So it might as well be **the 2nd**, **or something completely different and book/author specific**.

To top it off, this is a question of *interpretation*, even when sufficient context is given(which is sadly not the case), because when reading philosophical works, much broader context (starting from Artistoteles and Plato at least) is very often required to understand anything, not to mention that a lot of phylosophical works are open for interpretation, either by design, or due to the fact that there is no 100% secure way to deliver ALL the meaning from the author to the reader.

Comment: Google Books result for Wühler coughs up sth very specific, *Handbüchlein für Wühler: oder, Kurzgefasste Anleitung in wenigen ...* Heinrich Hoffmann - 1848 - ‎"Wühler. Definition: Wer den Vorschriften dieses Werkes gemäß handelt, ist einer;"

Comment: @vectory , yeah, for all we know, this might have even been a surname used to refer to a group of opponents. If I recall correctly, the usage of the Dutch -s Plural in surnames was not so usual yet. But I may be wrong.

Comment: Dann wäre es vielleicht näher an "wollen", "wählen". Aber wie kommst du überhaupt auf Niederländisch?

Comment: @vectory, ich meine, wenn wir von mehreren Menschen sprechen die denselben Nachnamen tragen, z.B. von einer Familie, fügt man ein -s zum Namen hinzu, z.B. "die Müllers fahren ans Meer". Ich glaube irgendwo gelesen zu haben, das soll aus dem NIederländischen kommen.

Answer (score 0):

This is an excerpt from Prof. Konrad's essay *"Das Problem der Philosophie und seine Geschichtliche Evolution"*<sup>[1]</sup>.

In the corresponding paragraph, the systematic, in Konrad's opinion traditional way of pursuing philosophy is contrasted with the unsystematic, disjointed way of thinking. A metaphor for this unsystematic endeavor is the routing or scrabbling, in German *das Herumwühlen* or simply *Wühlen*, in ideas and thoughts. And someone who routs or scrabbles is a router or scrabbler, in German *Wühler*. Thus, *philosophische Wühler* is a metaphorical paraphrase for those philosophers who hold this way of thinking.

---

<sup>[1] In: Zeitschrift für Philosophie und philosophische Kritik. Volume 33. Edtiors: Fichte, Ulrici, and Wirth. Halle, 1858. See [page 61 on Google Books](https://books.google.de/books?id=dEhTCLRp-noC&pg=PA61&dq=Eine%20Zeit%20lang%20wird%20die%C3%9F%20als%20System-%20oder%20Styl-losigkeit%20erscheinen&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFuYizm4zlAhWHyqQKHQGeCj4Q6AEIKzAA#v=onepage&q=Eine%20Zeit%20lang%20wird%20die%C3%9F%20als%20System-%20oder%20Styl-losigkeit%20erscheinen&f=false).</sup>